# How can I disable my laptop from reinstalling uninstalled drivers?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, drivers, keyboard

I've uninstalled the driver for the onboard keyboard, because it keys in random keys, but everytime I restart it reinstalls the onboard keyboard drivers. I've tried renaming the keyboard driver in the Windows folder, but I can't; it says I need from permission from TrustedInstaller. And I can't access the group policy because mine is the standard that doesn't have `gpedit.msc`. How can I prevent it from reinstalling the driver?

- OS: Windows 8
- Laptop model: Acer v3 772g

Comment: @DavidPostill nope not windows 7, 8. also tried the answers on that post but nothings working for me.

Comment: [You can use this software to remove the driver](http://driverstoreexplorer.codeplex.com/), if you ever need it again you can use System File Checker built into windows to restore it.